# Set button size to size of image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button

I have a couple of buttons that I am displaying on my application GUI using the following XAML in my WPF project:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="backBtn_Click" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
    <Image Source="C:\...\arrow_left.png" Height="30" Width="30" />
</Button>
<Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="RefreshBtn_Click" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
    <Image Source="C:\...\arrow_loop3.png" Height="30" Width="30" />
</Button>
```

However, when I run my application, the buttons appear to be bigger than the size of the images I'm displaying on them- i.e. the images are 30x30, but the buttons are rectangular, rather than square, with their height being greater than their width.

I am drawing the buttons next to each other, in a row with a few other buttons to give a 'menu bar' look at the top of the application window. However, because the height of these buttons is displaying a greater value than what I've set, there is a bit of 'white space' being shown along the menu bar, above and below other buttons that are being displayed with the height value that I've set, for example:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="referThis" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="80">
    <TextBlock>Send Reference</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

With this button, it would seem that because I am displaying text, and not an image on it, it has kept to the height & width values that I have set, but this means that it has some 'white space' above and below it, since the other buttons are causing the `<StackPanel>` where I've placed these buttons to take up more vertical space than I had intended.

How can I force the buttons on which I am displaying images to display at the size I have set them?

**Edit**

It seems that this was to do with what happens when I manually resize the window when the running the application- that the `<StackPanel>`/`<TabPanel>` are automatically resized when the window is resized... I have set the `Height` of the `<StackPanel>` to a specific value, and this now means that the buttons are all restricted to that size, so they all stay the same size, which is great.

But, when I resize the window, this causes the `<TabPanel>` that they are in to be resized, so I end up with white space above and below the buttons- is there a way that I can stop this?

Answer (score 1):

Set the button's VerticalAlignment to the top.
Set the desired width/height on the button and not the image.
Do this via the [Margin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Also check out [Alignment on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
Then set the image's stretch to Stretch.Fill.

Alternatively, something in you style might be throwing you off, because this

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0">
        <Image Width="30" Height="30" />
</Button>
```

Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

This code is exactly what you want:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
    <Image Source="image.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Button>
```

Note Padding and BorderThickness values which fit the image to the button.
As RoyalPotato said you can change button Width and Height and the image size will be dynamically stretched.